# Comparar valores de dos df con multiples condiciones en r

Tags: r, comparaciones

Tengo dos **df**, el primero contiene el ID de los empleados y la fecha en la cual realizaron una orden. El segundo contiene el ID de empleado y el intervalo de fecha en la cual estuvieron operando.

Los df tienen numero de filas diferentes. Necesito crear una nueva tabla donde solo traiga los valores del df1 que cumplan con la siguiente condicionen:

FechaOrden del **df1** se encuentre dentro del intervalo de la *Fecha inicio* y *Fecha fin* del **df2**, tomando en consideración el código de empleado. Para eso tiene que validar cada registro del df1 y compararlo con cada registro del df2.

Es decir, que verifique *df1[1,1] == df2[1,1] * luego *df1[1,1] == df2[2,1]*

También puede ser, crear una columna nueva en el df1 que diga true o false dependiendo de si la FechaOrden coincide con alguna de las filas dentro del intervalo de la FechaInicio y FechaFin, tomando en cuenta el IDde empleados.

DF1

| EmpleadoID | FechaOrden |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 02-25-2024 |
| 02 | 02-12-2024 |
| 03 | 01-12-2024 |
| 02 | 03-15-2024 |
| 01 | 01-22-2024 |
| 02 | 01-18-2024 |

DF2

| EmpleadoID | Fecha Inicio | Fecha fin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 02-17-2024 | 02-21-2024 |
| 02 | 02-02-2024 | 02-14-2024 |
| 03 | 01-19-2024 | 01-28-2024 |
| 02 | 03-21-2024 | 03-24-2024 |
| 01 | 01-02-2024 | 01-08-2024 |
| 02 | 01-14-2024 | 01-21-2024 |
| 05 | 01-11-2024 | 01-12-2024 |
| 02 | 01-04-2024 | 01-09-2024 |

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```r
for (i  in length(df1$EmpleadoID)){
      for(j in length(df2$EmpleadoID)){
               data$Validar <- if(df1[i,1]==df2[j,1]){
                                   ifelse(df1[i,8] >= df2[j,3]&
                                          df1[i,8]<=df2[j,4], 
                                     "Si",
                                     "No")
      
}
}
}
```

Si no utilizo la condicional if para que solo haga el proceso si el ID del df1 coincide con el ID del df2,realiza el proceso pero el resultado siempre es no porque hace la validación en todos los empleados.

Pero al utilizar el código arriba me lanza el siguiente error:

```r
Error in if (df1[i, 1] == df2[j, 1]) { : 
  valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El algoritmo que imagino intentaste implementar sería:

- Recorrer cada fila de `df1`
- Por cada fila de `df1` recorrer las filas de `df2` y verificar si es el mismo empleado y `FechaOrden` esta incluida entre las fechas de `df2`

Esto puede implementarse por ejemplo así:

```
resultado <- list()
for (i in 1:length(df1$EmpleadoID)) {
    existe <- FALSE
    for(j in 1:length(df2$EmpleadoID)) {
      if (df1[i,1]==df2[j,1] & df1[i,2] >= df2[j,2] & df1[i,2] <= df2[j,3]) {
          existe <- TRUE
          break
      }
    }
    resultado[[i]] <- existe
}
df1$Existe <- resultado

df1

  EmpleadoID FechaOrden Existe
1          1 2024-02-25  FALSE
2          2 2024-02-12   TRUE
3          3 2024-01-12  FALSE
4          2 2024-03-15  FALSE
5          1 2024-01-22  FALSE
6          2 2024-01-18   TRUE
```

Comentarios

- `for (i  in length(df1$EmpleadoID))` no genera una secuencia, técnicamente tus ciclos solo interan una sola vez, lo correcto en todo caso sería `for (i  in 1:length(df1$EmpleadoID))`
- El primer `for` recorre `df1`, el siguiente `for` recorre `df2` pero este último se detien con un `break` si encontramos una coincidencia
- Trabajamos con la lista `resultado` que va a tener tantos elementos como filas en `df1`, agregar un elemento se hace con doble corchete y reutilizando el índice de `df1` (`resultado[[i]] <- existe`)
- Por último llevamos los valores de la lista a una nueva columna en `df1`